# jQuery menu slide hover glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a menu with < divs > and am using mouseover mouseout functions to append and remove a tongue (like a description for each menu icon). The issue I am having is when I hover over the tongue, it executes (correctly) the mouseout function for the button and removes the tongue.

How can I prevent this? Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/QZ75D/

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseover', '.1, .2, .3, .4, .5', function(){
    var tongue = '<div class = "tongue">'+$(this).attr('value')+'</div>';
    $(tongue).appendTo($(this)).animate({width:"toggle"});
});
$('#wrapper').on('mouseout', '.1, .2, .3, .4, .5', function(){
    var that = $(this);
    $('.tongue').animate({width:"toggle"},function(){
        that.children('.tongue').remove();
    });
});
```

Bonus: The text also is affected by the width animation. Any way to fix that?

Comment: try adding a conditional statement. if mouseover .tongue, don't remove... something like that

Comment: or take a different approach. On mouseover, show() .tongue and then hide() when you mouseover on the test panel

Comment: I had tried that condition and it created some bizarre effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ75D/13/)**

You can do the following to make your code work as expected.

- Use `mouseleave` event instead of `mouseout` this will make sure child elements are detected as part of parent element and the event will only trigger when mouse leave element and it's child element.
- Similarly change `mouseover` event with `mouseenter` this event will only trigger if cursor enter element or its child.
- To avoid text from collapsing use `white-space: nowrap;` on `.tongue` class.

**JS:**

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseenter', '.1, .2, .3, .4, .5', function () {
    var tongue = '<div class = "tongue">' + $(this).attr('value') + '</div>';        
    $(tongue).appendTo($(this)).animate({
        width: "toggle"
    });
});
$('#wrapper').on('mouseleave', '.1, .2, .3, .4, .5', function () {
    var that = $(this);
    $('.tongue').animate({
        width: "toggle"
    }, function () {
        that.children('.tongue').remove();
    });
});
```

**P.S:** Try to avoid class names like `.1, .2, .3` they might work in java-script but they wont work in CSS.

CSS does not allow class names which start with numbers, instead you can try `.n_1, .n_2, .n_3 ....`

Comment: I know, sorry. I just wrote that for the fiddle.

Comment: Also thanks. Any idea how to make it so that, while the animation is playing, it cannot be interrupted? EG while the tongue is sliding you can mouseover it and it freaks out.

Comment: We can add conditions and detect if an animation is in progress to avoid tongue from freaking out & i will give it a try once i get some time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need JavaScript for this, depending on the level of support you need.
I made an example in which I altered the HTML structure a bit, to make it a bit more semantic IMO.
Animation wouldn't work in old IE, but functionality will (IE8).

HTML:

```
<ul class='wrapper'>
    <li class="button">Test</li>
    <li class="button">Test</li>
    <li class="button">Test</li>
    <li class="button">Test</li>
    <li class="button">Test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:50px;
    margin-left:40%;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: button-number
}

.button {
    counter-increment: button-number;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.button:before, .button:after {
    content:"Button number " counter(button-number);
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right: 50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.button:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s, visibility 1s;
    transition: transform .4s, visibility 1s;
}

.button:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
}

.button:hover:after {
    width: 300px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ75D/17/)

Notes:

- The :after element is there to prevent the "tongue" from disappearing if the mouse leaves immediately to the left.
- Animating `transform` instead of `width` is better for performance (element is not re-drawn) and eliminates weird text-wrapping during the animation.

Comment: Great answer. Ultimately there's enough things that don't work on IE9 and below that I would have to re-write my whole website.

Comment: It's up to you and who you are targeting. I think IE9 users are about 8% and IE8 are 5%, as of the time of writing this. Even they will get the functionality, just not the animation, because of the `visibilty` fallback.